# How to create gutters in Golden Grid System

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, golden-grid-system

How to create gutters in Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi? https://jonikorpi.com/golden-grid-system/.

Comment: The golden grid site is gone. Found this: https://jonikorpi.com/golden-grid-system/ that may be useful info to you.

Comment: @fzzylogic that is the system I'm talking about in my question

Comment: @ricebunny hey can you hlep me with this ?